# How to enable sort and filter in mongoose with Reference fileds in react-admin

Tags: node.js, mongoose, query-string, react-admin

I have 2 routers in `node.js` and `mongoose`

**1. Organization router** return list of organizations

```
router.get('/api/organizations/', async (req: Request, res: Response) => {

let { sort, filter } = req.query;
sort = sort == undefined ? {} : [JSON.parse(req.query.sort as string) || {}];
filter = sort == undefined ? {} : JSON.parse(req.query.filter as string) || {};


const organizations = await Organization.find({ filter }).sort(sort);

res.setHeader('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'Content-Range');
res.setHeader('Content-Range', 'organizations 0-20/500');

res.send(organizations);
```

});

**2. Projects router**: return list of projects each project related to one organizations.

```
router.get('/api/projects/', async (req: Request, res: Response) => {

let { sort, filter } = req.query;
sort = sort == undefined ? {} : [JSON.parse(req.query.sort as string) || {}];
filter = sort == undefined ? {} : JSON.parse(req.query.filter as string) || {};


const projects= await Projects.find({ filter }).sort(sort);

res.setHeader('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'Content-Range');
res.setHeader('Content-Range', 'projects0-20/500');

res.send(projects);
```

});

I want to enable both sort and filter in each router, but it is possible that both will be send one of them or neither.

in `react-admin` the client using with `ra-data-simple-rest` dataProvider, I have resources to organizations and projects,

**Projects List**

```
 <List {...props}>
   <Datagrid  rowClick="edit" >    
       <TextField source="name" />
        <ReferenceField source="organizationId" reference="organizations">
            <TextField source="name"/>
        </ReferenceField>
        <EditButton  />
    </Datagrid>
</List>
```

in the projects list the `ReferenceField` doesn't show the organization field if the sort and the fiter are declared int the routers.

I'm stuck,
How can I enable sort and filter on the routers but leave the option of ReferenceField?
any idea?

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

with `ra-data-simple-rest`, a `<ReferenceField>` issues a REST query looking like:

```
GET http://my.api.url/posts?filter={id:[123,456,789]}
```

You probably need to add some special logic in your controller to handle array values in the filter. The MongoDB syntax for that is `{ $in: array }`.

So I'd transform the `filter` before passing it to Mongoose, with something like:

```js
filter = Object.keys(filter).reduce((acc, key) => {
   const value = filter[key];
   acc[key] = Array.isArray(value) ? { '$in': value } : value;
   return acc;
}, {});
```

Comment: Thank you! .but, I didnt understand how the mongoose find query should get filter and the sort options? it is possible that both (sort & filter) will be send one of them or neither. I'm stuck how to handle in all this cases. because if they were not send I have it shows error of undefined

Comment: Look at the beginning of my answer: the filter is passed as a query parameter (after the "?"). Your Node.js controller must grab it from the request object (which is what you did in your example) and pass it to mongoose.

Comment: I mean how to pass it to mongoose? like this:
const projects= await Projects.find({filter}).sort(sort)?

Comment: I don't know Mongoose, but according to their doc (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) it should be something like `await Projects.find(filter).sort(sort)`